# Calculating Angles from Spatial Points in R

Tags: r, loops, spatial, angle

I am looking at some dispersal data and would like to get distance between points and also the angle between those points.  So far, I have only been able to achieve the first part.  Using the teal data from the adehabitatLT package I have done this:

```
require("adehabitatLT")
require("sp")
data("teal")
teal <- teal[1:10 ,]
capsd <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = SpatialPoints(coords = 
    teal[, c("x","y")], proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
    +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")), data=teal)
capdistance <- as.data.frame(pointDistance(capsd))
```

The capdistance is a 10x10 dataframe displaying the distances between the first 10 points of the teal dataset.

Does anyone know how I would calculate the angle between these points to create a similar matrix to the capdistance data.frame?  I have searched, but so far I have not found anything that would calculate the angle between two set locations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

So I have been looking around and it would seem that the bearing function from the geosphere package would be useful for this, but I am still (at least) a step away from working this all the way through:

```
require("geosphere")
capbearing1 <- bearing(capsd[1:10 ,], capsd[1 ,])
capbearing2 <- bearing(capsd[1:10 ,], capsd[2 ,])
```

I could repeat this ten times to achieve ten lists each one giving the angle of one of the ten points relative to all ten points (itself and the nine others); however, I would really like this to operate smoothly to give all ten lists at once as a single matrix; again, any help is very appreciated.

cygps gave some good code if you are utilizing UTMs in a single zone and have limited data points, so try that out if you have those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo <- function(df) {
      x1 <- x2 <- df$x
      y1 <- y2 <- df$y
      Xpair<-merge(x1,x2)
        names(Xpair)<-c("x1","x2")
      Ypair<-merge(y1,y2)
       names(Ypair)<-c("y1","y2")

      dist <- c(sqrt((Xpair$x1 - Xpair$x2)^2 + (Ypair$y1 - Ypair$y2)^2), NA)

      dx <- c(Xpair$x1 - Xpair$x2, NA)
      dy <- c(Ypair$y1 - Ypair$y2, NA)
      abs.angle <- ifelse(dist < 1e-07, NA, atan2(dy, dx))
      so <- list(dist,  abs.angle)
      return(so)
    }
```

I adapted this function from `adehabitatLT:as.ltraj`. It produces your distance and absolute angle matrices (assuming you wanted distances and angles between all points, not time-ordered distances and angles).

Comment: Thank you cgyps, this did work to produce the distances and angles like you said.  However, the list it outputs is a little bit bulky to deal with, I'm hoping someone would know how to create just the angles as a 10x10 matrix; this way they could be more easily referenced.

Comment: So, taking another look at this, it actually doesn't work out that well for this data set because the x and y data are in longitude/latitude.  I think that this would work if you were dealing with something like UTMs that were in the same zone though.

Comment: You can change the function so it only outputs the angles. And it is not advisable to calculate any distance measures using lat/long. Definitely convert to UTM first!

Comment: Even if the distances were removed you would still end up with a bulky dataset instead of a 10x10 matrix; again this is just for ease of referencing the data, but if you were dealing with something larger (say 100 points) you wouldn't want something that was 10,000 records long.  As far as switching to UTMs for distance calculation, that isn't really necessary; the points are all spatially referenced, so when the pointDistance command is applied to the capsd object, everything is fine.  The output is in meters, but as long as the CRS was correct originally there is no problem.